# MVC4 page stops loading early in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem loading a specific page in IE8 and I'm stumped on this one.  It seems to stop after a specific number of model calls.  Here is my partial code where the problem is happening.  The content is loaded using callbacks.

```
<div style="overflow: visible; height: 600px">
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 20px; font-family: "OpenSansSemibold"; color: #404040'>@Model.xblack </div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 19px; font-family: "OpenSansSemibold"; color: #439467'>@Model.xgreen </div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 17px; font-family: "OpenSansSemibold"; color: #b61c1c'>@Model.xred</div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 16px; font-family: "OpenSansSemibold"; color: #094ab2'>@Model.xblue</div>
<div class='detailsheading'>Description</div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px'>@Model.desc</div>
<div class='detailsheading'>Description in laymans terms</div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px'>@Model.cdesc</div>
<div class='detailsheading'>Guidelines</div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px'>@Model.guideline</div>
<div class='detailsheading'>Coverage</div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px'>@Model.coverinst</div>
<div class='detailsheading'>Reference</div>
<div style='float:left; width: 680px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px'>@Model.reference</div>
```

Right after Model.cdesc the page stops loading.  If I view source.  There is nothing after that field.

But it's not this field,  If I replace the field with another, that field will be the last displayed.

I have no idea how to even start trying to explain this.  I've tried having it display in compatibility mode and IE7 mode, and it doesn't work.

The page loads fine in IE7,IE9,IE10, Chrome and Firefox.

Does anyone have a clue what could be happening.  I'm sure you may need more information.  Ask and I will give you what I can.

Comment: Based on the HTML, I think IE simply gave up on it in disgust ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from importing memo fields from fox pro into the SQL database I'm pulling the data from.  By copying the memo field contents over I was able to get it working.  I'm not sure why this is, but I assume it has something to do with the text type.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see if you get any HTTP errors. And then you can work from that information. Also do compare the requests and replies coming from Firefox and IE8 - that can give you some tips and places where to start debugging.